# How to set HighLightColorBrush dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using following code in ComboBox template -

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"></SolidColorBrush>
```

I tried to put "Red" color and it is working, but binding is not.

Comment: Are you overriding the system colors? Why is the key `x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"`?

Comment: do you mean Color's binding not effect?
Please use Snoop to check your binding is or not correct. Maybe you need converter

Comment: It is a duplicate, I remember looking for that question, it's the same user too.